# how to make apache work with outlook?

Tags: php, outlook

i have a small console application which connects to outlook with using com.

My console application is meant to be invoked from php code . when i try on my local development box it works fine, when i try with on servers just from command line it works just fine however when i try to invoke it from php code it fails to work.

this is what i have done so far ?

i am new to software development and from what i can think of i looked at the configs files and nothing stands out and also the httpd.exe runs as a system user in development box as well as productions so that is fine .

Am i missing any thing any pointer to work in the right direction is helpful thanks a lot.

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on your dev server, but not on your production server, it sounds like a permissions issue with the Apache user not having access to execute at the command line. It could also be due to a php configuration (see your php.ini file) on your production server.

Comment: Which php configuration setting?

Comment: how do i find out which user apache is running on in windows ?

Comment: i looked around a lot but i did not find any thing in php.ini that is related to this.

Comment: Depending on what version of PHP, you might want to make sure safe_mode is set to Off.